# Problem with Multidimensional array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vuejs2, vue-router

Multidimensional Arrays

[image: Multidimensional Arrays]

Event Table

[image: Event Table]

We have multiple objects, inside each object we have got arrays and each array have objects.[Multidimensional Arrays] 
We want to check if problem.user_id is exist in users.id(current logged in user)
If it does then button will be disabled and if it doesn't then it return false.

But we got all arrays like given 'Event Table' screenshot.

```
<tr  v-for="event in events.data" :key="event.id">
                  <td>{{ event.user.id}} </td>

                  <td>{{event.user.name }}</td>

                  <td >{{ event.id}}</td>


                  <td >{{ event.problem[0].problem}}</td>


                  <td  >
                      <div v-for="problem in event.problem" :key="problem.id">
                        <div >
                          <div v-if="problem.user_id ===users.id">
                            <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="true">
                              <i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Already Joined
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div v-else="">
                            <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="false">
                              <i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Join
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                  </td >
                  <td> <a href="#" @click="editModal(event)">

                        <i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i>
                    </a>
                    /
                    <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(event.id)">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>

                  </tr>
```

Comment: Is it a typo that you wrote v-if=“problem.user_id ===user**s**.id”? I don’t see users.id in your screenshot only user_id.

Comment: Sry, I checked your question again, and you mention users.id there.

Comment: But can you output both values (like to the console) right before the v-if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to display only one button, either "Join" or "Already Joined" (disabled), right? If I get it right, I think you don't want to iterate `event.problem`, so you should replace this code:

```
<div v-for="problem in event.problem" :key="problem.id">
    <div >
      <div v-if="problem.user_id ===users.id">
        <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="true">
          <i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Already Joined
        </button>
      </div>
      <div v-else="">
        <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="false">
          <i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Join
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this:

```
<div v-if="event.problem.find(p => p.user_id == users.id)">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="true"><i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Already Joined</button>
</div>
<div v-else>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="false"><i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Join</button>
</div>
```

Here is a simplified demo:

```js
let data = []
for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
  let problems = []
  for (j=0;j<i+1;j++) {
    problems.push({
      user_id: j,
    })
  }
  data.push({
    id: i,
    user: {id: i, name: `user ${i}`},
    problem: problems,
  })
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: {id: 1},
    events: {data: data},
  },
  methods: {
    editModal: function(e) {},
    deleteUser: function(eid) {},
    participet: function(e) {},
  }
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<table id="app">
<tr>
  <th>User id</th>
  <th>User name</th>
  <th>Event id</th>
  <th>Join</th>
  <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<tr v-for="event in events.data" :key="event.id">
  <td>{{ event.user.id}} </td>
  <td>{{ event.user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ event.id}}</td>
  <td>
      <div v-if="event.problem.find(p => p.user_id == users.id)">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="true"><i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Already Joined</button>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="participet(event)" :disabled="false"><i class="fa fa-smile" style="font-size:35px;"></i>Join</button>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" @click="editModal(event)">
      <i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i>
    </a>
    /
    <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(event.id)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is fully functional. Thanks a lot.